# VBA won't append http:// to text based file?

Tags: vb.net, append, text-files

I need the following line to write *START* http:// in VBA, however, it won't write the http:// part to the pgp (text based) file

whats the trick for this?

```
objWriter.WriteLine((TextBox5.Text) + "," + "     " + "START http://" + (TextBox6.Text)
```

This is the rest of the code if necessary:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\test.pgp"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
        objWriter.WriteLine((TextBox2.Text) + "," + "        " + "*" + (TextBox1.Text))
        objWriter.Close()
        MsgBox("The acad.pgp file was successfully appended…")
    Else
        MsgBox("File missing reinstall or contact vendor…")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\test.pgp"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
        objWriter.WriteLine((TextBox3.Text) + "," + "     " + "START " + (TextBox4.Text) + ", 1,,")
        objWriter.Close()
        MsgBox("The acad.pgp file was successfully appended…")
    Else
        MsgBox("File missing reinstall or contact vendor…")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\test.pgp"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
        objWriter.WriteLine((TextBox5.Text) + "," + "     " + "START http://" + (TextBox6.Text) + ", 1,,")
        objWriter.Close()
        MsgBox("The acad.pgp file was successfully appended…")
    Else
        MsgBox("File missing reinstall or contact vendor…")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: If this is VBA then you should probably be using `&` instead of `+` to concatenate strings.

Comment: I think this is vb.net.  Can someone confirm this and retag the question?

Comment: yeah, it's VB.NET. It's like posting Java code and calling it C#. I guess they are really similiar, but...

Comment: Some-guy, you have posted a number of mis-tagged and mis-stated questions at this stage. Please make an effort or you are likely to be down-voted for deliberate mis-tagging

Answer (score 0):

Try concatening with & instead +